# Get the first file with specific extension in a folder

Tags: c#, search, filesystems, memory-efficient

My WinForms app uses the file system to save its data, I read and write from a file that has a unique extension (that I created).

I want to make sure the file can always be found by my application, even if it is renamed or moved to a sub directory.

I saw the `Directory.GetFiles(…)` function but it gets **all** the files with the extension, which means it is going to keep searching even after the file was found.

My question is: Is there **more efficient** way to search this one file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. As you said, `GetFiles` will get all the files with the search filter and then return. You don't want that, you want [`EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead:

> An enumerable collection of the full names (including paths) for the files in the directory specified by path and that match the specified search pattern and option.

So, you basically want:

```
var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(yourCurrentParameters)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

So that LINQ will return as soon as the first match is found.